# Adding gradient to UISlider doesn't work

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uislider

I'm trying to add a gradient to the left side of a `UISlider` like this:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.frame
gradientLayer.frame.size.height = self.trackHeight
gradientLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

let trackImage = UIImage.imageWithLayer(layer: gradientLayer)
self.setMinimumTrackImage(trackImage, for: .normal)
```

**UIImage extention:**

```
class func imageWithLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, layer.isOpaque, 0.0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
}
```

For some reason, when I run the app I don't get a gradient, and I don't even get any color, it's just clear color (alpha) instead of the gradient.

Any idea what went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/jonhull/GradientSlider

Comment: @JitendraModi This isn't what I've asked...

Comment: Update your question with an image showing what you want your slider to look like when the thumb is in the middle of the slider and at the far right end of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

`CAGradientLayer` uses `CGColors` array as input. To solve your problem, consider using CGColor by changing this:
`gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]`
to this
`gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]`

**EDIT**
You may get a square edges on the `UISlider` left edge (min track image)! so in order to fix that, just alter your extension function this way:

```
class func imageWithLayer(layer: CALayer, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, false, 0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
}
```